# Looking for clarifications on how to build a group chat app using Sinch platform

Tags: sinch

I am trying to figure out how to use sinch to build a basic group messaging app. It looks pretty simple but I have a few questions to help me understand the platform:

1) It seems like the platform doesn't support multiple conversations for one user. For example facebook messenger allows you to have many conversations with different people (different chats). But sinch only lets you send a message to a user with no conversation meta data. Or is it possible to send your message with meta data?

2)Do you manage users on the sinch platform? This means creating user objects and giving them id's etc or must this be done on another platform like parse?

3)How do you handle messaging logs? Like if I send a message to someone that's not logged in- how do I save it and also send them a push notification that a message was sent?

Thanks for the help everyone- the documentation is a bit dilute so I haven't been able to find answers to these questions yet :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can send meta data with headers, to create your own meta data thing. But to be fair Sinch is more like multi recipient message than groups with channels.
2. No, we use delegated security
3. We will automatically deliver the message when the user logs on, we keep messages for 30 days for delivery.

Comment: thanks :) - Also is it possible to send multimedia like pictures and videos?

Comment: Sorry no, no at the moment.